# Dynamically mapping one class with different tables(Views)

Tags: hibernate

I have been using annotation based mapping to class. I have some sets of classes which should be mapped with the same view. & as our code structure is same for different views. I want to dynamically select this view & map it with classes
Eg- @Table(name="View1")
    class abc
    @Table(name="View1")
    class xyz
I have multiples Views i.e.tables Eg.View1,View2,View3. So how can map this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using annotation based. I used xml based configuration, & using conditions in servlet mapped different views to one class